# Why is symbol binding maintained in a dynamic symbol table?

Tags: linker, ld, elf, loader

My understanding is that -

(1) Symbol *binding* (global/local/weak) is used by the *linker* to limit the scope of a symbol to its defining object file or other object files/ libraries linked together, and determine whether it's overridable from them.

(2) Symbol *visibility* (default/protected/internal/hidden) is used by the *loader* to control whether a symbol within a linked binary is visible or interposable from different binaries.

Still, symbol tables in executables/shared-libs (i.e. linked binaries) maintain the symbol binding:

```
$ readelf --all /usr/bin/ls
...
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 139 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    **Bind**   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __ctype_toupper_loc@GLIBC_2.3 (2)
     2: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND getenv@GLIBC_2.2.5 (3)
     3: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND sigprocmask@GLIBC_2.2.5 (3)
...
```

Is my understanding correct? Is symbol binding used in load/run time in some way I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is symbol binding used in load/run time in some way I'm missing?

It sure is.

Normally you will only see `GLOBAL` and `WEAK` symbols in the dynamic symbol table -- there is no reason to put `HIDDEN` symbols into it.

If you have an *unresolved* `WEAK` symbol, and no other definition of that symbol, and take an address of it, the loader will resolve such symbol to `NULL`.

But if the symbol is *unresolved* and `GLOBAL`, you'll get a fatal loader error instead.

Example:

```
// x.c
#include <stdio.h>
extern int foo() WEAK;
void fun() {
  printf("In fun: &foo = %p\n", &foo);
}

// main.c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  void *h = dlopen("./x.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  if (h == NULL) {
    printf("Failure: %s\n", dlerror());
    return 1;
  }

  void (*fun)(void) = dlsym(h, "fun");
  printf("Success, calling fun() @%p\n", fun);
  fun();
  return 0;
}
```

```
gcc main.c -ldl

gcc -DWEAK="" -fPIC -shared -o x.so x.c &&
./a.out

Failure: ./x.so: undefined symbol: foo
```

Now with a weak symbol:

```
gcc -DWEAK="__attribute__((weak))" -fPIC -shared -o x.so x.c &&
./a.out

Success, calling fun() @0x7f6d37988109
In fun: &foo = (nil)
```

P.S. You can observe similar error with *direct* linking (without use of `dlopen`): you just need to build `x.so` with a weak symbol, link `a.out` against it, then rebuild `x.so` without the weak symbol.

Comment: "there is no reason to put PROTECTED or HIDDEN symbols into it" - did you mean LOCAL symbols?

Comment: @OfekShilon No, I don't -- `PROTECTED` and `HIDDEN` are distinct and different from `LOCAL`. But (obviously) `LOCAL` symbols don't belong in the dynamic symbol table either.

Comment: A PROTECTED symbol is definitely placed in the symbol table. It is not interposable but is visible and callable from outside the binary.

Comment: @OfekShilon You are right. Updated.